# Mentioning Academic Topper in mid level software engineer resume summary

Tags: resume, india

I have started writing my résumé. My summary includes following details:

> • Full Stack Application Developer
>
> • 3 years 8 months of industry experience with C#, Asp.Net MVC, T-SQL, Azure and other Microsoft technologies

I have also been an academic topper from school to engineering college, I want to include it in summary as well, should I mention it in summary? Also, need some help/pointers in wording the same.

Comment: Are you from India?

Comment: Yes from India, by academic topper I mean first ranker (or top 3) in class

Comment: If you think it will come across as positive and add value to your c.v. then theres no reason not to add it. Bear in mind they may ask you to prove these claims.

Comment: Consider getting is all on one page and no summary

Comment: @paparazzi Two page resumes are the standard in India. A US-style one page resume will most likely be tossed in garbage, not because the resume is bad but simply because most people would think it is "lacking".

Comment: 3+ years experience? No one cares. Don't we already have a question on this subject though?

Comment: @Paparazzi: And in Australia if you don't have two or three pages you're slacking. So it depends where you are.

Comment: @Lilienthal `3+ years experience? No one cares.` Why not?

Comment: Because at that point you have an established work history and every decent interviewer will ask you about that instead of bothering to discuss what you did in college. That said, perhaps India is different and "top 3" actually means something there, but I somewhat doubt it. (Also, please don't use back-quote code markup for quotes, used quotation marks and *italics* instead.)

Comment: @Lilienthal India is, by and large, no different. "Top 3" means *something* if the company is hiring a college graduate. For a candidate with 2 or more years of experience, it is, at best, an "interesting trivia". I emphasise the "something" because even for a college graduate, nobody attaches great importance to it. It is just one of those factors which help filter candidates to an extent. I imagine it works more or less the same in most countries, at least in IT.

Comment: Hello and welcome to the Workplace. Unfortunately [we don't do CV advice here](http://workplace.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic), so I'm voting to close. You still try the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/3060/the-water-cooler) though where someone might assist you. Good luck

Answer (score 2):

Usually a resume will have an education section in which you will describe honors that substantiate how well you did, e.g. "*magna cum laude*".

The further away you are from college the less relevant these distinctions are, but I am reasonably sure that some companies still hold academic achievement in high regard even years past graduation. Given this should take half a line on your resume, I would include it with your education.

This is U.S.-centric advice (your comments, but not your question, specify the geography).